# convolution of two continuous function

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution

I am having trouble how to convolution of two function. The two functions have pdf as follow

f(x1)=\begin{cases}
Q(\tau+1) & x_{1}=\tau\\
\phi(x1+1) & -\tau<x_{1}<\tau\\
Q(1-\tau) & x_{1}=-\tau
\end{cases}

f(x2)=\begin{cases}
Q(\tau+1) & x_{2}=\tau\\
\phi(x2+1) & -\tau<x_{2}<\tau\\
Q(1-\tau) & x_{2}=-\tau
\end{cases}

where $Q(\tau)=\int_{\tau}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx$ is Q function $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}$ is standard gaussain pdf. I facing problem to calculate convolution of this two function, i.e f_{$x_{1}$}*f_{$x_{2}$}. I tried with several methods but could not get the result

Comment: Your definitions are wrong!  $\int_{-\infty}^\infty fdx=\infty$.  Also your two function need to be better distinguished.  As stated the are both the same.  I edited your statement to make it readable.

Comment: It is not clear what the arguments for your functions are.  Are they $\tau$ or $x_k$?

Comment: Sorry! Now I edited. It would be really helpful for me if I could get the result.